# PHP email validation - filter validate and filter sanitize

Tags: php

Im new to PHP hence my code being on the messy side.I would like some advice on the best approach to sanitize the email using the FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL while using the FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL at the same time for my contact and login form. Is the following code below which I have developed correct any advice would be greatly appreciated?

```
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
} else {
    $email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there something you have identified as not working as you expect?

Comment: You might want to post here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: It works, Che displays no errors with my php. I understand my code
An why it’s written. I just wanted feedback on any improvements if I had the correct (if) else statements.I am fluent in other languages such as java,c# and many more. PHP is something I’ve taken up in addition to this. 

I have unlimited studying resources at hand via university but we also get told to use forums to network for advice. It’s kinda encouraged in this line of work.

Comment: You've just picked the wrong forum.  As long as you are comfortable with the input being sanitized.  And to then use that filtered version further on.  Some omit the filter.  Logically it looks fine to me.  You might be more accurate to compare to false for the validation.  Do post on codereview, it's a good terse piece of example code.

Comment: Thank you about the forum posting stuff , yes that’s cool Like I say it’s just a language I’m learning in my spare time Alongside the other ones. If I need a code review il definitely head over to the link you’ve suggested. It’s the first time I’ve ever had to register to stackoverflow. So by the sounds of it am I correct in saying if I have debugging issues with a given language I can post on this but if I need logical code review to do it over on that site.

Once again thank you very much

Comment: That's about the size of it.